# Struggling with displaying an image from firebase to screen (swiftui)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So I have been working on a chat for couple days with an explained guide in YT until things got out of hand, I am trying to take an image(url) of a specific user from my database(via firebase) and using WebImage() function and the result appears differently than expected, I did check if the user even has an image and he has

```
private var customNavBar: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 16){
            WebImage(url: URL(string: vm.chatUser?.profileImageURL ?? ""))
                          .font(.system(size: 25))
                          .scaledToFill()
                          .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                          .clipped()
                          .cornerRadius(50)
                          .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 44)
                                      .stroke(Color(.label), lineWidth: 1)
                          )
                          .shadow(radius: 5)

            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                Text("(vm.chatUser?.email.replacingOccurrences(of: "@gmail.com", with: "" ) ?? "")").font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))

            HStack{
                Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                Text("Online").font(.system(size: 12)).foregroundColor(Color(.lightGray))
            }
        }
```

I looked up on google for solution but most of them are dealing with storage and I am trying to get the image from the cloud firestore,
I would really appreciate if somebody help me out

Comment: What does `result appears differently than expected` mean? Please add more details and clarify your problem.

Comment: Where is the actual image stored online? And why not use Firebase Storage?

Comment: have you check Firebase Storage against this`vm.chatUser?.profileImageURL` URL ??

Comment: 1) I expect to get the image from the user but it does not reach there

Comment: 2) The image stored both in storage and in the database

Comment: 3) I don't how to check the Firebase Storage, I understand they are connected by UID but I have no clue how to get there